# What is the difference between "divided" and "sub-divided"?

Tags: meaning, difference

is there any major difference between "divided" and "sub-divided". and how can these words be used

Comment: To *subdivide* something means to further divide each major division into smaller divisions.

Answer (score 2):

'Sub-division' is usually used in relation to areas of land. Said areas have already been divided (E.g. separate 'lots' from a contiguous 'block'), so when somebody wishes to divide one of them further, they are said to be sub-dividing.